# Set a maximum year in datepicker jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have the following code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker( {
        year = today.getFullYear,
        format: " yyyy", // Notice the Extra space at the beginning
        viewMode: "years", 
        minViewMode: "years",
        yearRange: '1920 : year',
        autoclose: true,            
        });
        });
    </script>
```

as you can see I only need the year, but I don't want to pick the following years... I mean 2020, 2021, 2022... Shouldn't be even able to be picked.. I looked around but couldn't find a solution, can someone help me with that? Thanks

EDIT:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').keyup(function() {

    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var dateReg = /^\d{4}$/;

    if (dateReg.test(inputVal)) {
      $("#datemsg").html("Valid").css("color", "green");
    } else {

      $("#datemsg").html("Invalid date").css("color", "red");
    }
  });

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    format: " yyyy", // Notice the Extra space at the beginning
    viewMode: "years",
    minViewMode: "years",
    autoclose: true,
    endDate: new Date(),
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You can't put variable assignments inside an object.

Comment: What datepicker widget are you using? I assumed it was jQuery UI, but it doesn't have `format` or `viewMode` options.

Comment: You seem to be mixing options between jQuery UI and Bootstrap Datepickers. Bootstrap has no `yearRange` option, the documentation is [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: There's also no `viewMode` option, just `minViewMode` and `maxViewMode`.

Comment: I see... :( sorry I wasted your time this way... first time doing this stuff

Comment: So, if I want to check with regex my input my only option is to use the jQuery UI, right?

Comment: No, that's totally unrelated.

Comment: One question per post please. This question is about setting the maximum year, what does the regex have to do with that?

Comment: Why don't you just disable manual entry and just use the datepicker? That way they can't enter anything invalid.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, i'll go search on the internet how to do that! that's a neat work around!

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate `year` to your range string, cause js won't parse this variable:

```js
    year = today.getFullYear,
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        format: " yyyy", // Notice the Extra space at the beginning
        viewMode: "years", 
        minViewMode: "years",
        yearRange: '1920 : ' + year,
        autoclose: true,            
     });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @nircraft there was another answer with explanation, so I didn't exit mine, till other was accepted. Then the question went to some loooong discussion, and Barmar deleted his answer. I will add some details, but this seems to be not important at this case. Thank you for your attention :)